# BotUI: Show loading animation before actions

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, chatbot

Using [BotUI](https://botui.org/) ([Docs](https://docs.botui.org/)) I'd like to have the loading animation, which is displayed before messages appear, also displayed before actions (e.g. buttons) appear.

```js
var botui = new BotUI('hello-world');

botui.message.add({
  content: 'Hello world from bot!'
}).then(function() {
  return botui.message.add({
    delay: 3000,
    human: true,
    content: 'Hello world from human!'
  });
}).then(function() {
  return botui.message.add({
    delay: 3000,
    content: 'Another hello world from bot!'
  });
}).then(function() {
  return botui.message.add({
    delay: 3000,
    human: true,
    content: 'Another hello world from human!'
  });
}).then(function () {
  return botui.action.button({
    delay: 3000,
    action: [{
      text: 'Some button',
      value: 'button1'
    }, {
      text: 'Another button',
      value: 'button2'
    }]
  });
}).then(function (res) {
  if(res.value == 'button1') {
    console.log('Some button was clicked.');
  }
  if(res.value == 'button2') {
    console.log('Another button was clicked.');
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.botui-container {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.botui-messages-container {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.botui-actions-container {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.botui-message {
  min-height: 30px;
}

.botui-message-content {
  padding: 7px 13px 17px 13px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #595a5a;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.botui-message-content.human {
  color: #f7f8f8;
  background-color: #919292;
}

.botui-message-content.text {
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.botui-message-content.loading {
  background-color: rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.5);
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: center;
}

.botui-message-content.embed {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.botui-message-content-link {
  color: #919292;
}

.botui-actions-text-input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #595a5a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #919292;
}

.botui-actions-text-submit {
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #919292;
  background: #777979;
}

.botui-actions-buttons-button {
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background: #777979;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.botui-actions-text-select {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #595a5a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #919292;
}

.botui-actions-text-searchselect {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #595a5a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #919292;
}

.botui-actions-text-searchselect .dropdown-toggle {
  border: none !important;
}

.botui-actions-text-searchselect .selected-tag {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

.dot {
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #919292;
}

.dot:nth-last-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  animation: loading 0.6s 0.3s linear infinite;
}

.dot:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  animation: loading 0.6s 0.2s linear infinite;
}

.dot:nth-last-child(3) {
  animation: loading 0.6s 0.1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    background-color: #ababab;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(0, -3px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    background-color: #ababab;
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(0, 3px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botui/build/botui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botui/build/botui.min.css">
<div class="botui-app-container" id="hello-world">
  <bot-ui></bot-ui>
</div>
```

At least I managed to identify the relevant template part in [botui.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/botui/build/botui.js).

```
<div v-if=\"msg.loading\" class=\"botui-message-content loading\"><i class=\"dot\"></i><i class=\"dot\"></i><i class=\"dot\"></i></div>
```

But since the contents of the *botui-actions-container* are loaded only after the delay I am unable to display the loading animation before the buttons appear.

Comment: Pleeeaaase help me out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without changing the inner working of BotUI, by using `botui.message.add` (to use the `loading` feature) immediately followed by `botui.message.remove` using the `index` parameter of the last message. Then use the action you want. This makes the loading appears before the action as requested, despite `botui.action` not having a `loading` parameter.

Here is the code that I use, with `botui.action.button`, but you can use any action. If you use `delay: 0` for the action, the action appears instead of the loading, without any blank message that would appear if you do not remove the initial message.

```
// add an empty message to use the "loading" feature not available with action
botui.message.add({
    delay: 2000,
    loading: true,
    content: ''
}).then(function (index) {
    // get the index of the empty message and delete it
    botui.message.remove(index);
    // display action with 0 delay
    botui.action.button({
        delay: 0,
        action: [{
            text: 'Action 1',
            value: 'a1'
        }, {
            text: 'Action 2',
            value: 'a2'
        }]
    }).then(function (res) {
        botui.message.bot({
            delay: 1000,
            content: 'action chosen: ' + res.value
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what I'd call a smart solution. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to change the inner working of a third party component. This is normally a bad practice.
In this case probably the best way is to open a new issue [on their Github repository](https://github.com/botui/botui/issues). Ask them exactly what you need and maybe they will implement the requested feature for you.

Comment: It looks like it may be already possible by the way: https://docs.botui.org/guide.html#messages. Just add property `loading:true` inside the message object.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. And not, it's not possible this way.

Comment: Well, there is no other solution. You should just ask the programmers of bot-ui for help...

Comment: @FerryKranenburg, there is other solution, see below